# Paragraph migration for link field not working

Tags: 8, uri, paragraphs

I have below migration script for paragraph migration, where I have 2 fields,
(1) icon_type --> List(text) field type
(2) icon_url --> Link field type

### UPDATED WORKING CODE BELOW

If I run the migration script only icon_type is created but not the icon_url

```
id: icon_type_link
label: Icon Type Link
migration_group: devel
source:
 plugin: csv
 path: 'modules/custom/my_custom_module/data/icon_type_link.csv'
 keys:
   - id
 header_row_count: 1
destination:
 plugin: entity:paragraph
process:
 type:
      plugin: default_value
      default_value: icon_type_link
 uuid: uuid
 entity_id: entity_id
 icon_type: icon_type
 icon_url/uri: url
 icon_url/title: title
migration_dependencies: {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess both `icon_url` and `icon_type` are fields of your paragraph entity.
Remove the leading blanks in front of the line

```
icon_url:
```

until it has the same indentation level as `icon_type`.

(Whitespaces are very important in YAML: Indenting something blanks makes it a child of a previous line with less blanks. In your example `icon_url` has 2 blanks and therefor it is a sub value of field `icon_type`. With only one blank [same as `icon_type` and all the other fields] it means that `icon_url` is a direct child of the global `process` [the one without blanks].)

Comment: Yes icon_type and icon_url are is in same level, and YAML file is not showing any error.

Comment: Where is your `icon_url` source defined? Your `icon_url`destination uses an `icon_url` source that isn't defined anywhere directly, and I don't know the CSV source plugin, but I don't think it a CSV source fields with sub values.

Comment: Thank You for your reply.
This is my csv file data 
[
id,uuid,entity_id,icon_type,url,title
1,a7fdd984-c622-4d12-9888-308b4f032897,1,speaker-icon,http://google.com,Test Import ]

What source I need to add here?

Comment: Completly remove the `icon_url` destination with `iterate`, this is only needed when dividing one source column into multiple destinations. Instead do something like `target_field_name/sub_value_name: column_name_in_csv` (every field sub value in its own line on the same level)

Comment: Thank you Hudri. Now I made the changes(as mentioned by you) which is updated above and now it is working fine.